# Reccurent neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I watched the [this](https://youtu.be/dr3vAuFH5io?t=523)  video on YouTube and copied the code. Why it does not work in M12? I mean `net[inData]`  and `rnnLayerForward[param, inData, state]` don't give the same result? What  change since then and how can I fix it? Slides can be downloaded [here](https://amoeba.wolfram.com/index.php/s/o5CPPCDX6KodlMs).

```
    rnnTimeStep[params_Association, input_, state_] := 
      Tanh[params["StateWeights"].state + params["InputWeights"].input + 
        params["Biases"]];
    rnnLayerForward[params_Association, input_, state_] := 
     Rest@FoldList[rnnTimeStep[params, #2, #1] &, state, input]

sequenceLength = 3;
featureSize = 2;
rnnStateSize = 1;
inData = RandomReal[1, {sequenceLength, featureSize}];
state = ConstantArray[0, rnnStateSize];

net = NetInitialize@
  BasicRecurrentLayer[rnnStateSize, "Input" -> Dimensions@inData]

param = Normal@NetExtract[net, "Arrays"]

net[inData]

rnnLayerForward[param, inData, state]
```

Comment: `param = Normal[#] & /@ NetExtract[net, "Arrays"]`

Comment: Thanks. Can you please post as an answer, so I can accept it. `param = Normal/@ NetExtract[net, "Arrays"]` is also fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rnnTimeStep[params_Association, input_, state_] := 
  Tanh[params["StateWeights"].state + params["InputWeights"].input + params["Biases"]];

rnnLayerForward[params_Association, input_, state_] := 
 Rest@FoldList[rnnTimeStep[params, #2, #1] &, state, input]

sequenceLength = 3;
featureSize = 2;
rnnStateSize = 1;
inData = RandomReal[1, {sequenceLength, featureSize}];
state = ConstantArray[0, rnnStateSize];

net = NetInitialize@BasicRecurrentLayer[rnnStateSize, "Input" -> Dimensions@inData];

param = Normal[#] & /@ NetExtract[net, "Arrays"];
```

```
net[inData]
```

> {{-0.85818}, {-0.987016}, {-0.941039}}

```
rnnLayerForward[param, inData, state]
```

> {{-0.85818}, {-0.987016}, {-0.941039}}